# Angular 6 ngModel in ngFor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a problem with using ngModel in ngFor loop. I am making e-commerce app, and I want to get value of input with quantity, but every ngModel has the same name, so it's keep updating all of the inputs, like this: 
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipI0t.png)
And here is my page code:

```html
<div class="grid-container"> <!--  items  -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of items;" class="grid-item" >
      <img class="itemAv" src="{{item.imgUrl}}" width="100px" height="100px">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <p>${{item.price}}</p>
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
      <div class="buy">
       <input class="quants" name="quants" type="number" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="quants" placeholder = "1">
       <button class="buy" (click)="addToCart( item.name, item.price, quants , item.imgUrl )">buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how to solve this, or how to add dynamic ngModel names like 'quant+item.id'?

Comment: You can use template variable literal for this using ` backticks or use this: `[(ngModel)]="quants{{ item.id }}"`

Comment: I got an error that I can't use interpolation in ngModel :/

Comment: is you want your `quants` assigned from textbox to each and every item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a another property to your object array and then assign the `ngModel` like,

```
 <input class="quants" name="quants" type="number" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="item.quants" placeholder = "1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `item.quantity` to your items list and then you can do this:

```
<div class="grid-container"> <!--  items  -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of items;" class="grid-item" >
      <img class="itemAv" src="{{item.imgUrl}}" width="100px" height="100px">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <p>${{item.price}}</p>
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
      <div class="buy">
       <input class="quants" name="quants" type="number" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" placeholder = "1">
       <button class="buy" (click)="addToCart( item.name, item.price, item.quantity, item.imgUrl )">buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```